# How can I add /* at the beginning and */ at the end of a line in Vim?

Tags: linux, unix, vim, comments, vi

I want to do something like commenting a line like follows,

`/*commented line*/`

How can I do it? Is there any short cut command to achieve this task?

Comment: I suspect this kind of Q/A should go to a FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in command (even though Vim has a `'commentstring'` option to define the syntax). Toggling comments is a solved problem; don't try to invent your (poor) alternative. The most popular plugins (that I know) are:

- [The NERD Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218)
- [EnhCommentify.vim - comment lines in a program](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=23)
- [tComment - An extensible & universal comment plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173)
- [commentary.vim : Comment stuff out; takes a motion as a target](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3695)

Comment: What about https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary ?  That honestly is the best one I've used, since it doesn't use a lot of `leader` mappings.

Comment: @EvergreenTree: Sure, added to the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:s/^\(.*\)$/\/*\1*\//`.

If you want to create a macro, then something like `qa^i/*<ESC>A*/<ESC>q` associates to the name `a` the commands that comments the current line. If you want to use the macro you can type `@a`.